# Unity3d Android App can not be listed in Facebook AppCenter

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-app-center

I developed a game for Android with Unity3d. I am using the latest Facebook Unity SDK (Version 5.1).

The game is NOT published on the Google Play Store, yet.

I want to release it soon and I want Android to be a listed platform in the AppCenter.

For some reason I can not switch it on. It says: "This platform cannot be listed because it is either configured incorrectly or not supported in App Center".
I also created it as a canvas app. I can switch that on!

Is this because:

a) The Facebook Unity SDK is not support by the AppCenter (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/guidelines states that an Android App should use the Facebook Login SDK for Android, see "Eligibility Requirements")

b) The App is not published on Google Play.

c) A wrong configuration. What could this be? I filled in every possible box and uploaded the needed screenshots.

d) something else?!?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got problem solved with enabling single sign on in `settings->basic->android`.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's the solution!

Comment: Thanks! Weird that it's needed. What does it means that it "Will launch from Android Notifications"?

Comment: I have the same problem though I have single sign on Enabled, what could be the reason.